# How to run MySQL server automatically on system startup on Mac OS?

Tags: mysql, linux, macos

Every time I want to use `mysql` first time after running my computer, I need to start the server manually by doing

```
mysql.server start
```

in the command line.

My question is - how can I make it to run *automatically* during the system startup?

I was looking for some answer and found only a way to do it on Ubuntu/Debian Linux, however this way (using `update-rc.d`) does not work on Mac OS.

`mysql --version` gives me

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.13, for osx10.9 (x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Mac MySQL startup item. This adds a system prefs button and allows you to set this via a gui.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation-startupitem.html

Alternatively add (see link)

> MYSQLCOM=-YES-

to

> /etc/hostconfig